# Steam Trading Cards error "Cookies have been disabled"

Tags: steam, steam-trading-cards

I have had a few TF2 regular and foil trading cards and I want to sell them before they expire, however every time I try to sell them, a error prompt pops up saying "There was an error in selling your card. Make sure your browser cookies are enabled"
I don't know what this means, please help.

Comment: FYI: cards do not expire.

Comment: Are you doing this in a browser or are you using the Steam client?

Comment: Do you get this error when using a web browser or the steam client? If it is the first, have you tried turning on cookies. If it is the second, sounds like a bug with the client, try updating or logging in/out.

Comment: @ColinD Some (event) cards do.

Comment: I get it in the steam client, but i will now try it in chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common issue with no real solution.  The following has [worked for a lot of people](http://steamcommunity.com/discussions/forum/1/648816742360217739/#c864971765362227893):

> 1. Open Internet Explorer
> 2. Internet options ( Top right is a Gear Icon)
> 3. Go to Privacy tab
> 4. Advance
> 5. check " Override automatic cookie handling"
> 6. Select Accept for both First-Party Cookies & Thrid-Party Cookies
> 7. Check under " Always allow session cookies"
> 8. Ok > Apply > Ok
> 9. Close Internet Explorer and Restart Steam

However, this has not worked for me; I still have this problem sporadically.  The solution for me has been to skip Steam entirely by logging into [the Steam website](http://www.steampowered.com) using any browser, and selling my items from [the market page](http://steamcommunity.com/market/).

Comment: When you log in from a new device/browser, doesn't it lock you out of using the market/trading from that device/browser for 7 days?

Comment: I'm running mac, and I use Chrome, Thanks anyways!

Comment: @GeloDCastroid9: The engine used is the same regardless of what OS you run on, or what your browser of choice is.  But unfortunately I have no idea how you'd change these options from a Mac :\

Comment: This answer is wrong. Steam does not use the Internet Explorer Web Control. It uses webkit and that since several years. http://store.steampowered.com/uiupdate/

Comment: @Assylum: That's interesting, I didn't know that.  However, though I got that detail wrong, the answer itself is still correct; the only solution I can get to work is to access the Steam page from a web-browser.

Comment: Even from Firefox or Chrome this can still happen. I say this is a coding issue, not a end user problem.